# Raphael Javascript. Change text appearance in relation to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Does anyone know how to change the appearance of text in relation to its position against another object when using Raphael?

I have created a JS fiddle to demonstrate what I mean (link below).

In the example there is an orange rectangle and some text that partly overlaps it. I would like the text to show only when it is directly over the rectangle and to be hidden where it is not. I will be using translate to change its position.

Any help on this would be brilliant. Thank you.

[Link to JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sparked/axRa7/15/)

Comment: It seems to not be possible - see this thread  http://groups.google.com/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/9c5d31ae2dda66a7?pli=1

Comment: Thank you. I did a search for masking and it looks like someone may have got something working like that using an image: [http://2hats.net/_box/raphael/peel_test.html](http://2hats.net/_box/raphael/peel_test.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly it may be done this way using clip-rect. I'm not sure if its the right way.

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/axRa7/17/)

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 10,500,500);
var rect = paper.rect(10,100,200,100,3);
rect.attr({
fill: "orange",
stroke:"orange"});

var txt = paper.text(15, 180, "Hey diddle diddle\nThe cat and the fiddle\nThe dish ran away with the spoon\n The little dog laughed to see such fun\nAnd the cow jumped over the moon");

txt.attr({
    "text-anchor": "start",
    "font-family": "Arial",
    "font-size": "16px",
    "clip-rect": "10,100,200,100",
});
```

​